# Use "Esc" key to accomplish two tasks at once

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, key

On **[THIS](http://angelarusu.net/test/googleads_ima_html5_samples/advanced/ls.php)** page, I have a div with the class of "video-wrapper" witch, upon clicking the player's *toggle full screen button*, is dynamically added a "full-screen" class.

I aim to remove the "full-screen" class *not only* by using the toggle full screen button, but by pressing the "Esc" on the keyboard. foe this purpose I have written the code:

```
$(document).on('keyup',function(evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 27 && $('.video-wrapper').hasClass('full-screen')) {
        console.log(evt.keyCode);
        $('.video-wrapper').removeClass("full-screen");
        $('input.fullscreen').removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

The problem is that this takes *two* "Esc" key strokes instead of one. The first just exists the browser's full screen mode and the second removes the "full-screen" class.

How can I exist the browser's full screen mode ***and*** remove the "full-screen" class with one "Esc" key stroke?

Comment: If you change it to `keydown` instead of up, does it work?

Comment: no, it dowes not

Comment: looks like a timing issue so a solution could be  to wrap all the code inside a time out function of around a tenth (100) of a second inside ($(document).on('keyup',function(evt) {) https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-settimeout-function-examples/

Comment: No, I tested and the problem is not that.

Comment: oki, -- if you notice you have errors in the console you need to resolve (GET http://angelarusu.net/test/googleads_ima_html5_samples/advanced/l.css net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
ls.php:7 GET http://imasdk.googleapis.com/js/sdkloader/ima3.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
ls.php:8 GET http://angelarusu.net/test/googleads_ima_html5_samples/advanced/player_g2/scr_adnow.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
ls.php:306 Uncaught ReferenceError: Application is not defined
    at window.onload (ls.php:306)
window.onload @ ls.php:306)  you need to use https://........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', onFullScreen, false);
document.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', onFullScreen, false);
document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', onFullScreen, false);
document.addEventListener('MSFullscreenChange', onFullScreen, false);

function onFullScreen()
{
    if (document.webkitIsFullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || document.msFullscreenElement != null){ return false; }
    $('.video-wrapper').removeClass("full-screen");
}
```

Comment: What is this doing? Why does it need 4 different event listeners?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know if Esc is actually running your function or just doing it's native behavior? Perhaps you need `e.preventDefault`

Comment: I want it to do both.

Comment: Right. I think your first Esc is just natively exiting full screen but not running through the function.

Comment: How can I make it run  through the function?

Comment: Try this:

$(document).on('keyup',function(evt) {
    (evt).preventDefault;
    if (evt.keyCode == 27 && $('.video-wrapper').hasClass('full-screen')) {
        console.log(evt.keyCode);
        $('.video-wrapper').removeClass("full-screen");
        $('input.fullscreen').removeClass('active');
    }
});

Comment: I just did. No change resulted from that.